# Как в графане фильтровать по external_labels прометеуса?

Tags: devops, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Есть несколько кубернетисов со своими прометеусами - они сливают свои метрики в одну базу(victoriametrics) с помощью remote_write.У каждого прометеуса разные external_labels. C БД Victoriametrics Grafana забирает метрики, но получается каша из разых куберов. Нужно отфильтровать по разным кубернетисам.
Я догадываюсь, что для такого запроса как: `sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=''}/1024/1024) by (kubernetes_io_hostname)`
То что мне нужно будет выглядеть как то так:
`external_labels=kuber-dev and sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!=''}/1024/1024) by (kubernetes_io_hostname)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{image!='', kuber="dev"}/1024/1024) by (kubernetes_io_hostname)
```

Но не для всех выражений подходит подставлять kuber="dev".
Лучше всего было бы делать через разные датасоурсы в графане, но это работает в кластерной конфигурации Victoriametrics и только. https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html#url-format
Возможно как вариант - поставлю на каждый кубер Victoriametrics и с нее буду брать метрики.